# JetBrains Rider C# Application Requiring Administrator Privileges

Tags: c#, windows, manifest, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm trying to guess how to require administrator privileges for my application in *JetBrains Rider*. In *Visual Studio* there's the option to add "App.manifest" file, where you can set the property `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` and the application will require administrator privileges.

I find no way to do this in *JetBrains Rider*. How can I request administrator privileges using *JetBrains Rider*?

I'm developing a .NetFramework application using C# language. And this is my project structure:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a visual way for doing this on Rider, but you can manually do this by adding the ApplicationManifest tag to your .csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationManifest>path/to/app/manifest/app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then, create your app.manifest file and configure it the way you want!
(The app.manifest is usually located at your app Properties folder)

Comment: It surprisingly worked but I'm afraid it's because of Windows environment execution since JetBrains Rider doesn't recognize it and marks the file structure as incorrect. I think that manifest file overrides or conflicts some information in `AssemblyInfo.cs`.